# I need help finding this font

Tags: fonts

I'm working on a website and the client want this font to be used for the logo:

[image]

But he has no idea what the font is and the guys who created his old design are no longer in business. So if anyone knows the name of this font it would help me a lot. Thanks for the patience as this is a bit of a dull question.

**UPDATE:** This is what I manage to actually do using one of the fonts you've showed:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Your version looks a bit tighter than the original to my eye, maybe stretch it out horizontally a bit and/or add a hint more tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few similar-looking "open face" fonts around.  For example, from a quick search on myfonts.com, here's [LTC Goudy Open](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-goudy-open/):

[image: LTC Goudy Open sample]

or [Cloister Open Face](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/cloister-open-face/):

[image: Cloister Open Face sample]

or [Caslon Open Face](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/caslon-open-face/):

[image: Caslon Open Face sample]

or [Academy Engraved](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/academy-engraved/):

[image: Academy Engraved sample]

The distinctive foot of the "K" in your logo, descending below the baseline and under the dot, may well be a custom flourish added by the logo designer.

Comment: Thank you so much I actually didn't have much hope of finding it. yes you're right that is most likely the case with the design, would be easy to do it in illustrator, I shall post it when I re-do the logo for completion's sake

Comment: here u go http://i.imgur.com/x6PJM.png

Comment: None of those are close. You can tell by the curvature of the serifs or "feet" in all of the examples. The source has mostly 90 degree angles on all of the extensions, with curvature on the inside of the "E"

Answer (score 1):

I tried [What the Font?](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but there were no significant matches. A little here and there but nothing exact.

He probably did a custom job and you can either a) trace it or b) recreate it. It's not a very detailed font at all and would probably take all of an hour to recreate. After all, you are just doing it for a logo and not trying to create an entire set that works perfectly together with upper/lower and glyphs etc. You know what you need and it's right there so I'd just recreate and have fun while I was doing it.

Comment: Would be good if you could name some of those matches, if they look kind of similar. Being a new website, perhaps the owner would accept another font (considering they lost the original one, a re-design could be great for them).